# How to add elements to a map if the keys from another map are not present

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a stream that takes a list of objects, and creates a map by grouping them by an ID and counting the repetitions for each element. 
However before closing the stream and returning the map, I need to check if all the IDs (keys) from another map (which I already have) are present in the new one, if not I have to add them with the default value 0. 
It's important to do such operation in the same stream, as I'm trying to learn and really want to make the code as compact and readable as possible.

The following is the first part of the code, I now need to check which IDs from the other map are not present in the new one created, and add them with the value 0.

```
return bookings.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.getID(), Collectors.counting()));
```

EDIT:

To clarify, this is what I need to do, but I'd like to do all the operations below in the original stream.

```
Map<Integer,Long> res = bookings.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.getID(), Collectors.counting()));
map2.keySet().stream().forEach(r -> res.putIfAbsent(r,0L));
return res;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, but *"make the code as compact and readable as possible"* is almost impossible. One solution you might want to look at is `Collectors.collectingAndThen()`. With this collector you can add an finisher to a given collector. so you can run `Map.putIfAbsent()` for all keys in the finisher:

```
Map<Integer, Long> result = bookings.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Booking::getCampoID, Collectors.counting()),
                map -> {
                    map2.keySet().forEach(k -> map.putIfAbsent(k, 0L));
                    return map;
                }));
```

But actually the code you already have looks also very compact and readable to me.